# Angular 2 autosuggest with editable div and RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a simple editable div :

```
<div #editable editable=true (keypress)='seach(editable.innerText)'></div>
```

In my component class i have the search method :

```
....
....
search(event: any) {
 Observable.from(event)
  .debounceTime(200)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap((query: any) =>  this.myService.searchUser(query))
  .subscribe((response: any ) => {this.results = response.data;                 });

}
```

The problem is that the search query is executed with only one letter after another. How can a keep the previous values of my stream ? for example if I search for 'House', the seach method will execute 'H' then 'o' then 'u'...etc

Comment: And what's the problem? That's why you have `debounceTime()` to avoid pooling the server too often. Or you want to keep all previous responses?

Comment: It's a search feature, so debouceTime() is to avoid pooling too often, and the problem is that i want to keep the previous taped letter so i can search a complete word.

Comment: So you're receiving only a single letter the user pressed in `query`. I'm not sure what `.innerText` returns with `editable=true` component so maybe you could use `.textContent` instead?

Comment: For example, want to search for 'javascript', When I log the received text I have: 

    j
    ja
    jav
    java
    javas
    .......

Comment: But what you get now is j a v a s ?

Comment: yes, when a search for 'javascript', my search service take letter one by one and : 
...api/seach='j'
...api/seach='a'
...api/seach='v'
.......................

Comment: In principe your code should work, however, I have doubts about the observable from event logic. Not sure that works as expected as you are creating a new stream for every key stroke it seems.

Comment: @MikeOne exactly, the code create a new stream for every keystroke, and that is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div #editable contenteditable=true (keyup)='search(editable.innerText)'>test</div>
      <div #editable contenteditable=true (keyup)='_searchSubject.next(editable.innerText)'>inline without search function</div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  private results;
  private _searchSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  ngOnInit() {
    this._searchSubject
        .debounceTime(200)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(input => console.log(input));
        // dont want to fake it.. :)
        //.switchMap((query: any) =>  this.myService.searchUser(query))
        //.subscribe((response: any ) => {
        //  this.results = response.data;
        //});
  }

  search(val: any) {
    console.log('search', val);
    this._searchSubject.next(val);
  }
}
```

- use `(keyup)` instead of `(keypress)` => otherwise you wont get the last key
- use a global subject to subscribe and use `next` on your search function

working demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/xYkU0QGZnsSaa38EQcDd?p=preview

**UPDATE**

To filter "empty" inputs, do it like this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this._searchSubject
      .debounceTime(200)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .filter(input => input) // BUT can lead to weird behaviors???!
      .subscribe(input => console.log('"' + input + '"'));
      // dont want to fake it.. :)
      //.switchMap((query: any) =>  this.myService.searchUser(query))
      //.subscribe((response: any ) => {
      //  this.results = response.data;
      //});
}
```

Comment: Your example works, but if i add the rest of the code it does not working any more, look like the second subscribe (or switchMap) does not catch the value !

Comment: You need to remove "my" subscribe if you uncomment your Code!! there can only be one subscription in this chain! :)

Comment: I know that i have to remove your subscribe, the problem is that a sequest with the query ' ' is send, and makes an error

Comment: See my updated answer.. Can't understand why you don't want that empty input.. Cause its wanted by the user? :) anyway.. `filter` should help here! :) or `map` and modify an empty input to anything else..